# Write the caption of table in left

Tags: tables, captions, positioning

I want write the caption of table like this:

[image: Figure1]

```
   \documentclass{article}
   \usepackage{caption}

   \begin{document}

    \begin{table}
    \caption{Caption}
    \label{tab:1}
    \begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}|c|c|}
     \hline
      Name & Sum\\
     \hline
      Square1 & 489.752  \\
      Square4 & 42.351  \\
      Ellipse & 600.12  \\
      \hline
      \end{tabular*}
      \end{table}
```

\end{document}

Comment: Did you see the `sidecap` package?

Comment: Also there are too many lines. Take a look at package `booktabs` and "The Chicago Manual of Style", for instance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically you want to use the `sidecap` package. I'll show a usage and also reformat the table to be more typographycally sound.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[leftcaption]{sidecap}
\usepackage{booktabs,siunitx} % better tables

\begin{document}

\begin{SCtable}
\caption{Caption}
\label{tab:1}
\begin{tabular}{lS[table-format=3.3]}
\toprule
\multicolumn{1}{c}{Name} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Sum}\\
\midrule
Square1 & 489.752  \\
Square4 & 42.351  \\
Ellipse & 600.12  \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{SCtable}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Don't try expanding tables beyond their natural width (a slightly wider intercolumn space would be acceptable): they are made to be read, not to fill space.